# Export/Print all Roles & Features

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2

I have putting together a guide on how to install a certain application. I know its working perfect on the servers current configuration so I thought it would be a easier to do an export from Server Manager or something similar.

Has anyone done this before or know of a tool which could display all services/roles in some sort of report?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In PowerShell:

```
Import-Module ServerManager

Get-WindowsFeature
```

Will show all possible roles and features and will indicate which ones are currently installed. The output looks like this:

```
Display Name                                            Name                   
------------                                            ----                   
[ ] Active Directory Certificate Services               AD-Certificate         
    [ ] Certification Authority                         ADCS-Cert-Authority    
    [ ] Certification Authority Web Enrollment          ADCS-Web-Enrollment    
    [ ] Certificate Enrollment Web Service              ADCS-Enroll-Web-Svc    
    [ ] Certificate Enrollment Policy Web Service       ADCS-Enroll-Web-Pol    
[X] Active Directory Domain Services                    AD-Domain-Services     
    [X] Active Directory Domain Controller              ADDS-Domain-Controller 
    [ ] Identity Management for UNIX                    ADDS-Identity-Mgmt     
        [ ] Server for Network Information Services     ADDS-NIS               
        [ ] Password Synchronization                    ADDS-Password-Sync     
        [ ] Administration Tools                        ADDS-IDMU-Tools        
[ ] Active Directory Federation Services                AD-Federation-Services 
    [ ] Federation Service                              ADFS-Federation        
    [ ] Federation Service Proxy                        ADFS-Proxy             
    [ ] AD FS Web Agents                                ADFS-Web-Agents        
        [ ] Claims-aware Agent                          ADFS-Claims            
        [ ] Windows Token-based Agent                   ADFS-Windows-Token     
[ ] Active Directory Lightweight Directory Services     ADLDS                  
[ ] Active Directory Rights Management Services         ADRMS                  
    [ ] Active Directory Rights Management Server       ADRMS-Server           
    [ ] Identity Federation Support                     ADRMS-Identity         
[ ] Application Server                                  Application-Server     
    [ ] .NET Framework 3.5.1                            AS-NET-Framework       
    [ ] Web Server (IIS) Support                        AS-Web-Support         
    [ ] COM+ Network Access                             AS-Ent-Services        
    [ ] TCP Port Sharing                                AS-TCP-Port-Sharing    
    [ ] Windows Process Activation Service Support      AS-WAS-Support         
        [ ] HTTP Activation                             AS-HTTP-Activation     
        [ ] Message Queuing Activation                  AS-MSMQ-Activation     
        [ ] TCP Activation                              AS-TCP-Activation      
        [ ] Named Pipes Activation                      AS-Named-Pipes         
    [ ] Distributed Transactions                        AS-Dist-Transaction    
        [ ] Incoming Remote Transactions                AS-Incoming-Trans      
        [ ] Outgoing Remote Transactions                AS-Outgoing-Trans      
        [ ] WS-Atomic Transactions                      AS-WS-Atomic           
[ ] DHCP Server                                         DHCP                   
[X] DNS Server                                          DNS                    
[ ] Fax Server                                          Fax                    
[ ] File Services                                       File-Services          
    [ ] File Server                                     FS-FileServer          
    [ ] Distributed File System                         FS-DFS                 
        [ ] DFS Namespaces                              FS-DFS-Namespace       
        [ ] DFS Replication                             FS-DFS-Replication     
    [ ] File Server Resource Manager                    FS-Resource-Manager    
    [ ] Services for Network File System                FS-NFS-Services        
    [ ] Windows Search Service                          FS-Search-Service      
    [ ] Windows Server 2003 File Services               FS-Win2003-Services    
        [ ] Indexing Service                            FS-Indexing-Service    
    [ ] BranchCache for network files                   FS-BranchCache         
[ ] Hyper-V                                             Hyper-V                
[ ] Network Policy and Access Services                  NPAS                   
    [ ] Network Policy Server                           NPAS-Policy-Server     
    [ ] Routing and Remote Access Services              NPAS-RRAS-Services     
        [ ] Remote Access Service                       NPAS-RRAS              
        [ ] Routing                                     NPAS-Routing           
    [ ] Health Registration Authority                   NPAS-Health            
    [ ] Host Credential Authorization Protocol          NPAS-Host-Cred         
[ ] Print and Document Services                         Print-Services         
    [ ] Print Server                                    Print-Server           
    [ ] LPD Service                                     Print-LPD-Service      
    [ ] Internet Printing                               Print-Internet         
    [ ] Distributed Scan Server                         Print-Scan-Server      
[ ] Remote Desktop Services                             Remote-Desktop-Services
    [ ] Remote Desktop Session Host                     RDS-RD-Server          
    [ ] Remote Desktop Virtualization Host              RDS-Virtualization     
        [ ] Core Services                               RDS-Virtualization-Core
        [ ] RemoteFX                                    RDS-RemoteFX           
    [ ] Remote Desktop Licensing                        RDS-Licensing          
    [ ] Remote Desktop Connection Broker                RDS-Connection-Broker  
    [ ] Remote Desktop Gateway                          RDS-Gateway            
    [ ] Remote Desktop Web Access                       RDS-Web-Access         
[ ] Web Server (IIS)                                    Web-Server             
    [ ] Web Server                                      Web-WebServer          
        [ ] Common HTTP Features                        Web-Common-Http        
            [ ] Static Content                          Web-Static-Content     
            [ ] Default Document                        Web-Default-Doc        
            [ ] Directory Browsing                      Web-Dir-Browsing       
            [ ] HTTP Errors                             Web-Http-Errors        
            [ ] HTTP Redirection                        Web-Http-Redirect      
            [ ] WebDAV Publishing                       Web-DAV-Publishing     
        [ ] Application Development                     Web-App-Dev            
            [ ] ASP.NET                                 Web-Asp-Net            
            [ ] .NET Extensibility                      Web-Net-Ext            
            [ ] ASP                                     Web-ASP                
            [ ] CGI                                     Web-CGI                
            [ ] ISAPI Extensions                        Web-ISAPI-Ext          
            [ ] ISAPI Filters                           Web-ISAPI-Filter       
            [ ] Server Side Includes                    Web-Includes           
        [ ] Health and Diagnostics                      Web-Health             
            [ ] HTTP Logging                            Web-Http-Logging       
            [ ] Logging Tools                           Web-Log-Libraries      
            [ ] Request Monitor                         Web-Request-Monitor    
            [ ] Tracing                                 Web-Http-Tracing       
            [ ] Custom Logging                          Web-Custom-Logging     
            [ ] ODBC Logging                            Web-ODBC-Logging       
        [ ] Security                                    Web-Security           
            [ ] Basic Authentication                    Web-Basic-Auth         
            [ ] Windows Authentication                  Web-Windows-Auth       
            [ ] Digest Authentication                   Web-Digest-Auth        
            [ ] Client Certificate Mapping Authentic... Web-Client-Auth        
            [ ] IIS Client Certificate Mapping Authe... Web-Cert-Auth          
            [ ] URL Authorization                       Web-Url-Auth           
            [ ] Request Filtering                       Web-Filtering          
            [ ] IP and Domain Restrictions              Web-IP-Security        
        [ ] Performance                                 Web-Performance        
            [ ] Static Content Compression              Web-Stat-Compression   
            [ ] Dynamic Content Compression             Web-Dyn-Compression    
    [ ] Management Tools                                Web-Mgmt-Tools         
        [ ] IIS Management Console                      Web-Mgmt-Console       
        [ ] IIS Management Scripts and Tools            Web-Scripting-Tools    
        [ ] Management Service                          Web-Mgmt-Service       
        [ ] IIS 6 Management Compatibility              Web-Mgmt-Compat        
            [ ] IIS 6 Metabase Compatibility            Web-Metabase           
            [ ] IIS 6 WMI Compatibility                 Web-WMI                
            [ ] IIS 6 Scripting Tools                   Web-Lgcy-Scripting     
            [ ] IIS 6 Management Console                Web-Lgcy-Mgmt-Console  
    [ ] FTP Server                                      Web-Ftp-Server         
        [ ] FTP Service                                 Web-Ftp-Service        
        [ ] FTP Extensibility                           Web-Ftp-Ext            
    [ ] IIS Hostable Web Core                           Web-WHC                
[ ] Windows Deployment Services                         WDS                    
    [ ] Deployment Server                               WDS-Deployment         
    [ ] Transport Server                                WDS-Transport          
[ ] Windows Server Update Services                      OOB-WSUS               
[X] .NET Framework 3.5.1 Features                       NET-Framework          
    [X] .NET Framework 3.5.1                            NET-Framework-Core     
    [ ] WCF Activation                                  NET-Win-CFAC           
        [ ] HTTP Activation                             NET-HTTP-Activation    
        [ ] Non-HTTP Activation                         NET-Non-HTTP-Activ     
[ ] Background Intelligent Transfer Service (BITS)      BITS                   
    [ ] Compact Server                                  BITS-Compact-Server    
    [ ] IIS Server Extension                            BITS-IIS-Ext           
[ ] BitLocker Drive Encryption                          BitLocker              
[ ] BranchCache                                         BranchCache            
[ ] Connection Manager Administration Kit               CMAK                   
[ ] Desktop Experience                                  Desktop-Experience     
[ ] DirectAccess Management Console                     DAMC                   
[X] Group Policy Management                             GPMC                   
[ ] Ink and Handwriting Services                        Ink-Handwriting        
    [ ] Ink Support                                     IH-Ink-Support         
    [ ] Handwriting Recognition                         IH-Handwriting         
[ ] Internet Printing Client                            Internet-Print-Client  
[ ] Internet Storage Name Server                        ISNS                   
[ ] LPR Port Monitor                                    LPR-Port-Monitor       
[ ] Message Queuing                                     MSMQ                   
    [ ] Message Queuing Services                        MSMQ-Services          
        [ ] Message Queuing Server                      MSMQ-Server            
        [ ] Directory Service Integration               MSMQ-Directory         
        [ ] Message Queuing Triggers                    MSMQ-Triggers          
        [ ] HTTP Support                                MSMQ-HTTP-Support      
        [ ] Multicasting Support                        MSMQ-Multicasting      
        [ ] Routing Service                             MSMQ-Routing           
    [ ] Message Queuing DCOM Proxy                      MSMQ-DCOM              
[ ] Multipath I/O                                       Multipath-IO           
[ ] Network Load Balancing                              NLB                    
[ ] Peer Name Resolution Protocol                       PNRP                   
[ ] Quality Windows Audio Video Experience              qWave                  
[ ] Remote Assistance                                   Remote-Assistance      
[ ] Remote Differential Compression                     RDC                    
[X] Remote Server Administration Tools                  RSAT                   
    [X] Role Administration Tools                       RSAT-Role-Tools        
        [ ] Active Directory Certificate Services Tools RSAT-ADCS              
            [ ] Certification Authority Tools           RSAT-ADCS-Mgmt         
        [X] AD DS and AD LDS Tools                      RSAT-AD-Tools          
            [X] AD DS Tools                             RSAT-ADDS              
                [X] AD DS Snap-Ins and Command-Line ... RSAT-ADDS-Tools        
                [X] Active Directory Administrative ... RSAT-AD-AdminCenter    
                [ ] Server for NIS Tools                RSAT-SNIS              
            [ ] AD LDS Snap-Ins and Command-Line Tools  RSAT-ADLDS             
            [X] Active Directory module for Windows ... RSAT-AD-PowerShell     
        [ ] Active Directory Rights Management Servi... RSAT-RMS               
        [ ] DHCP Server Tools                           RSAT-DHCP              
        [X] DNS Server Tools                            RSAT-DNS-Server        
        [ ] Fax Server Tools                            RSAT-Fax               
        [ ] File Services Tools                         RSAT-File-Services     
            [ ] Distributed File System Tools           RSAT-DFS-Mgmt-Con      
            [ ] File Server Resource Manager Tools      RSAT-FSRM-Mgmt         
            [ ] Services for Network File System Tools  RSAT-NFS-Admin         
        [ ] Hyper-V Tools                               RSAT-Hyper-V           
        [ ] Network Policy and Access Services Tools    RSAT-NPAS              
        [ ] Print and Document Services Tools           RSAT-Print-Services    
        [ ] Remote Desktop Services Tools               RSAT-RDS               
            [ ] Remote Desktop Session Host Tools       RSAT-RDS-RemoteApp     
            [ ] Remote Desktop Gateway Tools            RSAT-RDS-Gateway       
            [ ] Remote Desktop Licensing Tools          RSAT-RDS-Licensing     
            [ ] Remote Desktop Connection Broker Tools  RSAT-RDS-Conn-Broker   
        [ ] Web Server (IIS) Tools                      RSAT-Web-Server        
        [ ] Windows Deployment Services Tools           RSAT-WDS               
    [ ] Feature Administration Tools                    RSAT-Feature-Tools     
        [ ] BitLocker Drive Encryption Administratio... RSAT-BitLocker         
            [ ] BitLocker Drive Encryption Tools        RSAT-Bitlocker-DriveEnc
            [ ] BitLocker Recovery Password Viewer      RSAT-Bitlocker-RecPwd  
        [ ] BITS Server Extensions Tools                RSAT-Bits-Server       
        [ ] Failover Clustering Tools                   RSAT-Clustering        
        [ ] Network Load Balancing Tools                RSAT-NLB               
        [ ] SMTP Server Tools                           RSAT-SMTP              
        [ ] WINS Server Tools                           RSAT-WINS              
[ ] RPC over HTTP Proxy                                 RPC-over-HTTP-Proxy    
[ ] Simple TCP/IP Services                              Simple-TCPIP           
[ ] SMTP Server                                         SMTP-Server            
[ ] SNMP Services                                       SNMP-Services          
    [ ] SNMP Service                                    SNMP-Service           
    [ ] SNMP WMI Provider                               SNMP-WMI-Provider      
[ ] Storage Manager for SANs                            Storage-Mgr-SANS       
[ ] Subsystem for UNIX-based Applications               Subsystem-UNIX-Apps    
[ ] Telnet Client                                       Telnet-Client          
[ ] Telnet Server                                       Telnet-Server          
[ ] TFTP Client                                         TFTP-Client            
[ ] Windows Biometric Framework                         Biometric-Framework    
[ ] Windows Internal Database                           Windows-Internal-DB    
[X] Windows PowerShell Integrated Scripting Environm... PowerShell-ISE         
[ ] Windows Process Activation Service                  WAS                    
    [ ] Process Model                                   WAS-Process-Model      
    [ ] .NET Environment                                WAS-NET-Environment    
    [ ] Configuration APIs                              WAS-Config-APIs        
[ ] Windows Server Backup Features                      Backup-Features        
    [ ] Windows Server Backup                           Backup                 
    [ ] Command-line Tools                              Backup-Tools           
[ ] Windows Server Migration Tools                      Migration              
[ ] Windows System Resource Manager                     WSRM                   
[ ] Windows TIFF IFilter                                TIFF-IFilter           
[ ] WinRM IIS Extension                                 WinRM-IIS-Ext          
[ ] WINS Server                                         WINS-Server            
[ ] Wireless LAN Service                                Wireless-Networking    
[ ] XPS Viewer                                          XPS-Viewer
```